# Can a call to $http be made more concise?

Tags: angularjs

I find myself frequently using this construct in my controllers:

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: '../ajax/mycallback', cache: false}).
success(function(data) {
    $scope.data = data;
});
```

Is there any way to make this more concise? In particular, is there a kind of "default success method" that just stores the result on the scope? Also, is there a way to globally set cache to false, so I can use $http.get() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1: you only need to pass the value to $scope

`$http` returns a **promise**, so you can share the returning result directly with the scope:

```
$scope.data = $http({method: 'GET', url: '../ajax/mycallback', cache: false})
```

Angular has **automatic promise fulfillment support in templates**. So if you assign the `data` to templates, it will automatically trigger the **digest cycle** upon fulfillment (read: it will trigger the update when the $http will succeed).

But in this case I would suggest you to use `$resource` instead of `$http` and incapsulate the `$resource` creation as a service.

You also can use `$resource` the same way, as it has **natural automatic promise fulfillment**. *Natural* states that promises will be replaced with actual values (this logic includes **arrays** support!):

```
$scope.data = MyResourceService(...)
```

### Option 2: you have a more complex callback

You can simply create a **factory function** to create a closure within a specific scope:

```
function cb(scope, scopeObjName) {
    return function(data){
        scope["scopeObjName"] = data;
        // common logic goes here
    } 
}
```

and use it like this:

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: '../ajax/mycallback', cache: false})
.success(cb($scope, "data"))
```

As you can see, the answer depends on the actual usecase and can be improved further.

Comment: As far as I know option 1 is not longer working. The ability to map promise to scope directly was removed from framework.

Comment: Option 1 looks ideal for me. What a shame it is deprecated! I see their reasoning here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$parseProvider I did try re-enabling unwrapPromises but it didn't seem to work. Not tried $resource yet

Comment: Ok, $resource seems to be the answer! The following works without needing to enable unwrapPromises: $scope.longRunning = $resource('../ajax/longrunning').query(); Not checked cache behaviour yet

Comment: Yeah, sorry for misleading option 1. I was using this issue, but migrated to the $resource and lost the point with $http.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

```
myApp.config(function($httpProvider){
    $httpProvider.defaults.cache = false;  
});
```

as for your callback, If that is all you're doing, the anonymous function is the best option. Otherwise you'd have to bind a generic function every http invocation and pass it a context..like this:

```
$http.get(...).success(standardSuccess.bind({$scope:$scope,p:'data'}));

function standardSuccess(data){
    this.$scope[this.p] = data;  
}
```

Then you would just keep that in an injectable somewhere. But as you can see is more verbose and less readable. And slower.

Another option is to pass the scope into the httpConfig itself. and use an interceptor to set your property. (as the config is received in an interceptor. Roughly like:

```
myApp.config(function($httpProvider){
    $httpProvider.defaults.cache = false;
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('defaultHttpSetter');
});
myApp.factory('defaultHttpSetter',function($q){
   return {
       'response': function(response){
             response.config.scope[response.config.prop] = response.data;
             return $q.when(response);
        }
   };    
});
```

Which would be used like..

```
$http.get('/myurl',{scope:$scope,prop:'data'});
```

Comment: Aha! $httpProvider.defaults explains a lot. Thank-you, I hadn't managed to find that in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have issue with the other answers, but just in case they are over-thinking it.  You can do this:

```
var genericSuccessFunction = function(data) {
    $scope.data = data;
}
```

You can create your result function as part of the controller and save it as a controller local variable.

Then you just need to pass the result function into the success:

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: '../ajax/mycallback', cache: false}).success(genericSuccessFunction);
```

In my experience, I often find myself using this approach for an error function, but I don't often find myself able to use generic success functions.